# React Native Update App Without user needs to login again

Tags: react-native, app-store

So I have a React Native App. I want to publish it to the Playstore (Later to the Appstore too). Now if I want to make an update the user needs to login again, because I am just overwriting the old App File. How can I prevent it or is there a solution, where I don't need to publish the update to the playstore and just make changes and it gets updated directly without the user needs to update it through the App-/Playstore. I already saw **Microsoft Code Push** but I think first it costs money and second everybody can see the source code ? :)

Thank you for you help.

## Edit

So I want to know: If I update the App, is the Async Storage going to be reseted or will it just stay with the data in it?

Comment: Even if you overwritten the old App File, didn't you store the authentication token in the local storage already?

Comment: Yeah I use Async Storage, but doesn't it get set to null if I overwrite the App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dianaqqq already told you. If you update the App the Async Storage should not be affected from this, because it's not really a direct part of your app; it's more like a party of the whole system and your app uses this.

For more information read this:
**https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/**